# Free terminal time, integral objective and differential equations as constraints

Tags: time, terminal, final, gekko, optimal

I am trying to solve an optimal control problem that involves minimizing an integral objective with fixed states but free terminal time. It is a relatively simple problem that can be solved analytically. Gekko's solution doesn't match the analytical.

[image: Equations]

[image: Solution]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I followed several Gekko examples to solve this one. Any help is much appreciated.

Another problem I am having is how to let Gekko automatically calculate initial values of control. Optimal control always starts with the specified initial guess of control.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()
# time points
n = 501
tm = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
m.time = tm

# Variables
x1 = m.Var(value=1)  # x1
x2 = m.Var(value=2)  # x2
# u = m.Var(value=-1)  # control variable used as normal var
u = m.MV(value=-1) # manipulative variable
u.STATUS = 1
u.DCOST = 1e-5

p = np.zeros(n)
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)

# FV
tf = m.FV(value=10.0, lb=0.0, ub=100.0)
tf.STATUS = 1

# equations
m.Equation(x1.dt()/tf == x2)
m.Equation(x2.dt()/tf == u)


# Final conditions
soft = True
if soft:
    # soft terminal constraint
    m.Minimize(final*1e5*(x1-3)**2)
    # m.Minimize(final*1e5*(x2-2)**2)
else:
    # hard terminal constraint
    x1f = m.Param()
    m.free(x1f)
    m.fix_final(x1f, 3)
    # connect endpoint parameters to x1 and x2
    m.Equations([x1f == x1])

# Objective Function
obj = m.Intermediate(tf*final*m.integral(0.5*u**2))

m.Minimize(final*obj)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.NODES = 2
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.MAX_ITER = 500
# m.options.MV_TYPE = 0
m.options.DIAGLEVEL = 0
m.solve(disp=False)


# Create a figure
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
# plt.plot([0,1],[1/9,1/9],'r:',label=r'$x<\frac{1}{9}$')
plt.plot(tm, x1.value, 'k-', lw=2, label=r'$x1$')
plt.ylabel('x1')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(tm, x2.value, 'b--', lw=2, label=r'$x2$')
plt.ylabel('x2')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.plot(tm, u.value, 'r--', lw=2, label=r'$u$')
plt.ylabel('control')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.plot(tm, obj.value, 'g-', lw=2, label=r'$\frac{1}{2} \int u^2$')
plt.text(0.5, 3.0, 'Final Value = '+str(np.round(obj.value[-1], 2)))
plt.ylabel('Objective')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few modifications:

```py
# u = m.MV(value=-1)
u = m.MV(value=-1,fixed_initial=False)

#obj = m.Intermediate(tf*final*m.integral(0.5*u**2))
obj = m.Intermediate(m.integral(0.5*u**2))

m.options.NODES = 3 # increase accuracy
```

If you add a constraint that `tf<=3` then it gives the same solution as above.

[image: original solution]

However, if you relax the `tf` constraint to `<=100` then there is a better solution.

[image: better solution]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()
# time points
n = 501
tm = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
m.time = tm

# Variables
x1 = m.Var(value=1)  # x1
x2 = m.Var(value=2)  # x2
u = m.MV(value=-1,fixed_initial=False) # manipulated variable
u.STATUS = 1
u.DCOST = 1e-5

p = np.zeros(n)
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)

# FV
tf = m.FV(value=10.0, lb=0.0, ub=100.0)
tf.STATUS = 1

# equations
m.Equation(x1.dt()/tf == x2)
m.Equation(x2.dt()/tf == u)


# Final conditions
soft = True
if soft:
    # soft terminal constraint
    m.Minimize(final*1e5*(x1-3)**2)
    # m.Minimize(final*1e5*(x2-2)**2)
else:
    # hard terminal constraint
    x1f = m.Param()
    m.free(x1f)
    m.fix_final(x1f, 3)
    # connect endpoint parameters to x1 and x2
    m.Equations([x1f == x1])

# Objective Function
obj = m.Intermediate(m.integral(0.5*u**2))

m.Minimize(final*obj)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.NODES = 3
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.MAX_ITER = 500
# m.options.MV_TYPE = 0
m.options.DIAGLEVEL = 0
m.solve(disp=True)

# Create a figure
tm = tm*tf.value[0]
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
# plt.plot([0,1],[1/9,1/9],'r:',label=r'$x<\frac{1}{9}$')
plt.plot(tm, x1.value, 'k-', lw=2, label=r'$x1$')
plt.ylabel('x1')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(tm, x2.value, 'b--', lw=2, label=r'$x2$')
plt.ylabel('x2')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.plot(tm, u.value, 'r--', lw=2, label=r'$u$')
plt.ylabel('control')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.plot(tm, obj.value, 'g-', lw=2, label=r'$\frac{1}{2} \int u^2$')
plt.text(0.5, 3.0, 'Final Value = '+str(np.round(obj.value[-1], 2)))
plt.ylabel('Objective')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
Apparently, there are multiple solutions for final time, and Ipopt is using the first value. This is resulting in control variable being zeros at all time points. is there anyway to find multiples solutions of optimal control problem in Gekko. Or in general how to tackle such problems?

Comment: Multiple solutions indicate that the problem is non-convex. I typically use variable bounds such as `x>1e-3` to avoid finding those extra solutions. Changing the initial guess value can also be effective.